# Changes on controller do not affect the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I m on a mac and I m working on Dreamweaver. I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {       
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Modify what?!?!?!.";
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {       
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>              
}
```

Whenever I make a change on the controller's `ViewBag.Message` variable, the change doesn't affect the result.

Am I doing something wrong? Of course I don't compile anything, I just change the value of the variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to compile your code. Your controller code specifically won't function properly without compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of course I don't compile anything

That's the problem. Controller is a C# code file in the project, the project should be built for the changes to take place (unlike views, which are compiled on runtime).

**Update.** The reason this is different from PHP frameworks is that C# is a compiled language - it should be processed by the compiler into library/executable which is then executed. On the other hand PHP scripts are being run (mostly) directly, without any compilation.